# Cannot open connection, deploying Shiny app, tesseract trainingdata for other languages

Tags: deployment, shiny, path, permissions, tesseract

I've been struggling to deploy my shiny app using the tesseractpackage. It seems that it can't 'reach' the downloaded languages. In my case: English and Dutch.

When setting up the language, the resulting object should 'point' to a path. That's the part where shiny can't open the connection.

Any help would be much appriciated!

Kind regards, R

Below I've copied the error message and the relevant code.

**This is the error message I get after deployment:**

Warning in file(con, "wb") :
  cannot open file '/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/nld.traineddata': Permission denied
**Error in value[3L] : cannot open the connection**
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
Execution halted

**This is my code**

```
#loading software requirement
library(tesseract)

#download language (dutch)
tesseract_download('nld')
tesseract_download('eng')

#set language parameters for later use.
dutch <- tesseract('nld')
english <- tesseract('eng')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working myself. The key was taking the following steps:

1. Creating a subdirectory (of folder) which is called 'tessdata'. This subdirecty is the directory you can download the languages in and 'set' the languages.
2. When deploying your app, you have to deploy this tessdata-subdirectory as well. So in the deployement prompt, you 'tick' the boxes of this folder as well.
3. Then make sure the tesseract engine points at the following path:

Screenshot of how to upload the tessdata-folder along with the app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QQLJ.png)

Please see the code below

```
#loading software requirementlibrary(tesseract)

#Make sure the tesseract package is 'pointing' at the right 'parent directory'
#which is in this case the path your shiny app is working from.
#That's why you need the dot ("."). Which is in essence the workdir.

Sys.setenv(TESSDAT_PREFIX = ".")

#so combining the workdir and the pre-installed folder 'tessdata'
path <- paste0(getwd(), '/tessdata')

#use this path for downloading
#download languages (dutch and english)
tesseract_download('nld', datapath = path)
tesseract_download('eng', datapath = path)


#set language parameters for later use, using the same path
dutch <- tesseract('nld', datapath = path)
english <- tesseract('eng', datapath = path)
```